# What German consulate should I apply to for national visa? (India)

Tags: visa, germany

In India there are various German consulates. How do I figure out which German consulate to apply to?

I lived most of my life abroad in Kuwait, and there are various consulates in India, so I'm a bit confused as to where to apply.

Answer (score 3):

Germany has assigned the front-end part of visa processing to [VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/index.html), a corporation which provides processing services to many governments. See [this German Consulate in India page](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/2554096) for more information about this assignment.

If, for example, you are applying for a Schengen visa (generally for short-term tourist entry), review [this other German Consulate in India page](https://india.diplo.de/in-en/service/-/1908750). If you're applying for a German National Visa (type D, as for students or working), follow the instructions given on [this VFS page](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/apply-visa).

The latter page contains application information, noting that you must file a Schengen visa application for Germany with VFS, and not directly with a German Consulate in India. The page shows this text addressing your "where to apply" question:

> **Step 3:**
>
> Schedule an appointment for the submission of your visa application and submit it at the nearest Visa Application Centre. Kindly note that you have to pay the VFS Service charge already when booking the appointment.
> Applicants applying for a Schengen visa can submit their visa applications at any VFS centre across India as the application will be forwarded to the German Consulate General Mumbai for a decision.
> For further information, please visit the [VFS Global Website](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/)

Comment: I want the answer for student visa

Comment: @ReineAbstraktion I have amended my Answer to provide the VFS link to begin a Student VIsa application.

Comment: It's almost 1 month old but if the person has residency in Kuwait, he/she must apply from there.

Comment: The OP states in their question that they _lived_ (past tense) most of their life in Kuwait. That suggests to me that the OP now does not maintain residency in Kuwait; in addition, the OP asked about applying in India, not about applying in Kuwait.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply for a German National Visa at the German Consulate responsible for the area within India that you have as your **habitual residence**.

The definition to what the German Consulate considers to be the *habitual residence* (for a German National Visa) is explained inside the anwser to [germany - Why can't I apply for a visa from my home country when I am currently resident in another country? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/183885/95267)

Answer (score 0):

You need habitual abode of six months for application. Here is reply from the visa section of germany in bangalore

[image]