# Emergency visa extension in Kuwait

Tags: visa

I am applying for a German visa (again) this month as I had withdrawn my previous one from Kuwait. This is necessary as I can't apply from my home country at the moment due to lack of habitual abode.

The issue I have is, if the visa takes more than one month and a half to be processed, I would be in trouble due to my Kuwait residence expiring near the very end of November.

Is there any way to get an extension of the Kuwait family visa on the basis of this?

Comment: You can apply from your home country once you have returned, as explained in your previous question [What German consulate should I apply to for national visa? (India)](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/26673/17166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking around locally, I heard that one month of extension is possible following cancellation of visa. Three months if it is given with a reason, altho what constitutes a reason is not clear to me.